# Как запустить несколько проектов на Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Мне необходимо запустить сразу несколько разных проекта на эклипсе, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Нам в кнопке запуска можно же выбрать проект, вот выбирайте и запускайте

Answer (score 0):

Откройте первый проект, затем откройте второй. По идеи, второй должен открыться в отдельной вкладке. Примерно, вот так будет выглядеть вторая, открытая вкладка : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]